# JavaScript problem displaying a new window from client-side code

Tags: javascript, new-window

In Chrome and Edge this simple example results shows a "Click Me!" button that opens a new tab.

```js
function test() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "_newtab");
  myWindow.document.write("hello world");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">
    Click Me!
</button>
```

The issue is that the new tab appears to be still loading after it is displayed.

[image]

Comment: you can't actually run this code in stack overflow because window.open() returns null in this environment

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` implicitly calls `document.open` if the document isn't open for writing.

While it remains open for writing, the loading spinner will tick.

You need to explicitly close the document for writing to stop that:

```
myWindow.document.close();
```